# how to sort values in a horizontal bar graph that already has a variable

Tags: pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook, bar-chart

[image]How do I sort the values based on top10[ActiveCases]? I don't seem to get the syntax right.

```
top10=df[0:21]
top10
plt.barh(top10['Country,Other'],width=top10['ActiveCases'])
plt.title("Top 10 countries with highest active cases")
```

Comment: please provide a full reproducible example

Comment: I've added a picture of the unsorted graph. How do I sort it?

Comment: Sort your data before slicing? And please, the case numbers are high not the cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before creating the graph use

```
    top10 = top20
    top10.sort_values(by='ActiveCases')
    top10.head(10).plot(kind='barh')
```

this will plot the 10 highest countries